# leaflet markers dissapear in r shiny tabsetPanel (when on mobile)

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet

I'm working on a Shiny app that uses the leaflet package. My leaflet map is embedded in a tabsetPanel where the first tab shows a plot and when you click on the second tab you'll see the leaflet map with markers. Everything works fine as long as I'm on my computer.

However, when I open my shiny app on mobile, I can click on the second tab and see the map with markers. But when I switch back to the first tab (plot1) and scroll down and up again and then click on the second tab the leaflet markers have disappeared and the map shows only partially.

Is this a bug?

Here is a very simple example script:

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(leaflet)


df <- read.csv(textConnection(
"name,Lat,Long,total
Item1,36.879872,-85.335353,231
Item2,35.445454,-84.384953,123
Item3,36.395842,-85.452312,321
Item4,37.989796,-86.233434,123
Item5,38.857421,-87.342342,213"
))


ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
    column(8,
      h1("First Headline"),
        tabsetPanel(type = "tabs",
                   tabPanel("plot1", plotOutput("plot1")),
                   tabPanel("view map", leafletOutput("map"))
                   ) 
    ), # col end
  ), # row end
  fluidRow(
    column(8,
      h1("Another Headline"), plotOutput("plot2"),
    ), # col end
  ), # row end
) # fluidpage end



server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  # render plot1
  output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
    df %>% ggplot(aes(x = name, y = total, fill = total)) + geom_col()
  }, res = 96)

  # render leaflet
  output$map <- renderLeaflet({
    leaflet(df) %>% addProviderTiles(providers$OpenStreetMap) %>%
      addCircleMarkers(lng = ~Long, lat = ~Lat) 
  })
  
  # render plot2
  output$plot2 <- renderPlot({
   df %>% ggplot(aes(y = Long, x = Lat)) + geom_point()
   }, res = 96, height = 700)
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Maybe you can find something useful here https://jnolis.com/blog/shiny_mobile/

Comment: unfortunately I can't find anything there that would help me but thanks for your message

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by adding observeEvent. Leaflet now renders when switching to the second tab.

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(leaflet)


df <- read.csv(textConnection(
"name,Lat,Long,total
Item1,36.879872,-85.335353,231
Item2,35.445454,-84.384953,123
Item3,36.395842,-85.452312,321
Item4,37.989796,-86.233434,123
Item5,38.857421,-87.342342,213"
))


ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
    column(8,
      h1("First Headline"),
        tabsetPanel(id = "tabs", type = "tabs",
                   tabPanel(value = "tab1", "plot1", plotOutput("plot1")),
                   tabPanel(value = "tab2", "view map", leafletOutput("map"))
                   ) 
    ), # col end
  ), # row end
  fluidRow(
    column(8,
      h1("Another Headline"), plotOutput("plot2"),
    ), # col end
  ), # row end
) # fluidpage end



server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  # render leaflet second tab is active
  observeEvent(input$tabs,{
    if(input$tabs == "tab2")
      output$map <- renderLeaflet({
      leaflet(df) %>% addProviderTiles(providers$OpenStreetMap) %>%
        addCircleMarkers(lng = ~Long, lat = ~Lat) 
    })
  })
  
  # render plot1
  output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
    df %>% ggplot(aes(x = name, y = total, fill = total)) + geom_col()
  }, res = 96)

  # render plot2
  output$plot2 <- renderPlot({
   df %>% ggplot(aes(y = Long, x = Lat)) + geom_point()
   }, res = 96, height = 700)
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```